# Concerning the usage of the verb "differentiate"

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

"TRT World Research [Center] will differentiate from the crowded and competitive landscape of the research business…"

I found that this sentence sounded odd. I'd think that you'd need an object after the verb "differentiate": "…differentiate itself from the crowded and competitive landscape of the research business…"

Is this a question of syntax or grammar? If it is a question of the latter, would you need to add another object before "from"?

Comment: Grammar and syntax are mostly synonymous. Grammar often tends to be used informally for a larger set of things, including spelling, but here syntax and grammar both refer to the order of words, and which words are expected to go with which other ones.

Answer (score 1):

It’s not a matter of either syntax or grammar, but **semantics**. The sentence itself is correctly formed, but its meaning is not clear.

You can *differentiate* from a boat, for example, but the meaning is not complete until the listener knows that you’re looking at a flock of birds and trying to distinguish the herons from the flamingos.

The writer probably meant to say that TRT World Research would differentiate *itself* from the common herd of competitors, but slipped in his or her thought process, and mentally placed the organization within the herd.

Comment: If the sentence needs an object before it is to make sense (which I agree it does), then it is not correctly formed.

Comment: I can't seem to find a definitive answer to my question online, but I've looked at a bunch of dictionaries and all of the examples I am seeing have two objects (except those that exemplify the technical meaning of the word). Those examples exclusively include "differentiate between this and that" or "differentiate this from that."

Comment: An object can be implicit.  A sentence containing a transitive verb does not have to have a formal object within the sentence itself, e.g. *The Golf Club Juniors Program treats boys and girls equally so long as their physical abilities are broadly similar. It differentiates from age thirteen onwards.*